PJsip onFrameRecieved function giving lots of noise in audiostream
``Hi all,
We are using PJSIP for calling purposes on Android. When we use the onFrameReceived method to receive audio frames, we are encountering a lot of noise. We then pass these frames into a GStreamer pipeline, which sends them to a specific port. However, when we receive this audio from that port, it is still full of noise.
Could anyone help us troubleshoot this issue?
here is on frame recieved function  of java
public void onFrameReceived(MediaFrame frame) 
{
    Log.i("ashish", "Receiving callback on frameReceived");

    // Check if the frame is valid
    if (frame == null) {
        Log.e("ashish", "Received a null MediaFrame");
        return;
    }

    // Get the size of the audio data
    int size = (int) frame.getSize(); // Get the size (number of shorts)
    Log.d("ashish", "Audio data size: " + size);

    // Convert buffer to Short[]
    Short[] audioDataShort = frame.getBuf().toArray(new Short[0]);

    // Check if audioDataShort is not null and has the expected length
    if (audioDataShort == null || audioDataShort.length == 0) {
        Log.e("ashish", "Received empty audio data");
        return;
    }

    if (audioDataShort.length != size) {
        Log.e("ashish", "Size mismatch: expected " + size + ", got " + audioDataShort.length);
        return;
    }

    // Create a byte array to hold the data
    byte[] audioData = new byte[size * 2]; // Each short is 2 bytes

    // Convert Short[] to byte[]
    for (int i = 0; i < audioDataShort.length; i++) {
        // Convert each short to byte array in little-endian order
        audioData[i * 2] = (byte) ((audioDataShort[i] >> 8) & 0xFF);         // Lower byte
        audioData[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (audioDataShort[i] & 0xFF); // Upper byte
    }

    // Debug: Log the byte array
    Log.d("ashish", "Audio Data Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(audioData));

    // Call the native method to send the byte array
    nativeSend(audioData, size); // Send the byte array and its length

}
we ARE USING NATIVE C++ CODE  TOO PUT AUDIO IN GSTREAMER PIPELINE
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_GStreamerApp_pushBuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray        buffer, jint length) 
{
if (buffer == NULL || length <= 0) {
    return; // Handle error
}

jbyte *nativeBuffer = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buffer, NULL);
if (nativeBuffer == NULL) {
    return; // Handle error
}

CustomData *data = GET_CUSTOM_DATA(env, thiz, custom_data_field_id);
if (data == NULL || data->send_src == NULL) {
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, nativeBuffer, 0);
    return;
}

GstBuffer *gstBuffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(length);
if (gstBuffer == NULL) {
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, nativeBuffer, 0);
    return;
}

// Fill the GStreamer buffer with audio data
gst_buffer_fill(gstBuffer, 0, nativeBuffer, length);

// Push the buffer into appsrc
GstFlowReturn ret = gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(data->send_src), gstBuffer);
if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
    GST_ERROR("Error pushing buffer to appsrc: %d", ret);
}

(*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, nativeBuffer, 0);
 }

AND HERE IS PIPLINE
static void *send_data_pipeline(void *userdata) {
    CustomData *data = (CustomData *)userdata;
    GstBus *bus;
    GError *error = NULL;

    GST_DEBUG("Creating pipeline in CustomData at %p", data);

// Create pipeline and elements
data->send_pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("data-pipeline-send");
data->send_src = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "source_send");
data->send_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "storage_queue");
data->send_capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "filter");
data->send_sink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "sinksend");

// Check for element creation
if (!data->send_pipeline || !data->send_src || !data->send_sink || !data->send_queue || !data->send_capsfilter) {
    GST_ERROR("Failed to create elements in the pipeline.");
    return NULL;
}

// Set properties for the sink and source
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->send_sink), "host", "172.16.7.73", "port", 5000, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->send_src), "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, "is-live", TRUE, NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->send_src), "buffer-size", 4096, NULL);

// Create and set caps
GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_from_string("audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, channels=(int)2, rate=(int)8000");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data->send_capsfilter), "caps", caps, NULL);
gst_caps_unref(caps); // Unreference the caps after setting

// Add elements to the pipeline
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data->send_pipeline), data->send_src, data->send_capsfilter, data->send_queue, data->send_sink, NULL);

// Link elements
if (!gst_element_link_many(data->send_src, data->send_capsfilter, data->send_queue, data->send_sink, NULL)) {
    GST_ERROR("Elements could not be linked.");
    return NULL; // Cleanup if necessary
}

// Set the pipeline to the playing state
gst_element_set_state(data->send_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

// Start processing bus messages
bus = gst_element_get_bus(data->send_pipeline);
gboolean running = TRUE;




  gst_element_set_state(data->send_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_object_unref(bus);
  gst_object_unref(data->send_pipeline); // If needed, depending on your ownership semantics

  return NULL;
}`

`
